# Becoming a good solidity developer

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm a javascript / web3 developer, with not much experience writing solidity. I have a lot of experience interacting with contracts using web3. What would be the best steps to start learning and becoming a competent solidity developer. I can write basic contracts but I don't have a proper understanding of all the fundamentals. Can anyone recommend a good course or place to start. Thanks

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJWh7F3AFyQ_x01VKzr9eyA and the hackathon videos of ChainLink on youtube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a perfect course recently launched by Patrick Collins and freecodecamp! Here's the link - https://youtu.be/gyMwXuJrbJQ